# Can I use this blade to cut Hardy Side-paneling

Tags: circular-saw, backer-board

Is the saw blade in the photo appropriate to cutout a window in HardyPanel?  Wood paneling?

https://www.homedepot.com/p/James-Hardie-HardiePanel-HZ10-5-16-in-x-48-in-x-96-in-Fiber-Cement-Sierra-8-Panel-Siding-9003080/305684630

What exactly is the nomenclature for this blade (if I wanted another I would ask for ????)?

The CDC recommends [polycrystalline diamond tip (PCD) blades](https://www.cdc.gov/niosh/docs/wp-solutions/2015-185/pdfs/2015-185.pdf).

[image]

Comment: it would burn through wood paneling more than cut through it. hardiboard would take forever.

Comment: that blade is designed for cutting things like tile and stone. MK Diamond doesn't have an exact match on their website, but this: http://www.mkdiamond.com/tile/bld_00_dry.html shows very similar blades.

Comment: hardie board siding panels or hardie backer?  I have cut both many times and there really is a difference.

Comment: @Dmoore Thank you for the clarification question.  OP update to address question

Answer (score 1):

That's a stone/tile/masonry cutting blade with a diamond 'turbo' rim.
[image]
It will work for Hardie Backer board or similar fiber-cement products but it'll make a *lot* of dust, and would almost certainly be awful at cutting any sort of wood or wood paneling - more likely to burn through than cut it.

Some other rim types for diamond blades are:
Continuous [image]
Segmented [image]
Segmented Turbo [image]

Answer (score 1):

Blades are described by the number of teeth. For example,  24T , 40T, 80T. Just ask for a hardboard blade which will be labeled as such and have very few teeth. One sold at the orange big box has 4 teeth, is made by Diablo (top of the line quality) but sells for $45. Store Sku 619584. This is a specialty blade that you won't find everywhere.

DIABLO  7-1/4 in. x 4-Teeth Polycrystalline Diamond (PCD) Tipped James Hardie/Fiber Cement Saw Blade
https://www.homedepot.com/p/DIABLO-7-1-4-in-x-4-Teeth-Polycrystalline-Diamond-PCD-Tipped-James-Hardie-Fiber-Cement-Saw-Blade-D0704DH/100627137

Answer (score 1):

I think your real question is "How can I cut backer board with a circular saw". The diamond blade in your picture is a **grinding blade**. It's designed to work with a variety of hard surfaces from tile, to cement, to even metal (not ideal for metal but I digress).

Backer board can be hazardous to cut because it contains silicates (as your CDC link notes), which can become airborne and get into your lungs and make you sick. The "weekend warrior" one-room-job answer doesn't involve power tools at all. Just use a simple utility knife, score the board, and then snap it (works well for drywall too). Minimal dust, but hard to make precise cuts where there's no long straight edge.

Your CDC link notes this

> Use  polycrystalline  diamond-tipped  (PCD)  blades  de-signed  to  be  used  to  cut  fiber-cement  siding.  Compared  to  Carbide-tipped  blades,  they  provide  a  cleaner  cut  of  the siding, exhibit a longer wear life, and may reduce the dust generated.

The power saw answer involves a special type of blade specifically made for fiber board

[image: Fiber board blade]

You can buy these in 4-10" sizes commonly. Note the low number of teeth, which are designed to minimize dust. A diamond grinder blade can do it too, but it's not designed to minimize dust because it's literally designed to chip away at material, not cut it clean like a saw blade. **Always wear a respirator if you use a power tool to cut fiber board, regardless of the method**

## TL;DR

Go to your local hardware store and ask for a "fiber cement blade" in the size your saw takes (6.5" or 7.25"). They're pricey, but they're the right tool for the job.

Comment: This is absolutely the right answer for the hardie siding... but is he asking about that?

Comment: Yes, siding please