# Mask for Cutting Hardie Board

Tags: safety

Is there a standard mask to protect the lungs when cutting Hardie board?  While specifics masks suggestions are appreciated, I am trying to understand how to avoid sub-standard masks and avoiding injury.

For additional context see [Can I use this blade to cut Hardyboard?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/218081/56573)

Comment: Whatever you do set your stand a good 30' plus from your house so once you cut you aren't sucking it in otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are talking about HardieBacker cement board, the [manufacturer's SDS](https://www.jameshardiepros.com/getattachment/41b4866d-f948-4c27-87b5-4215280281c1/sds-fiber-cement-interior-REPLACED-2015-06-08-AJW.pdf) (Safety Data Sheet) recommends using an N-95 (minimum) respirator/dust mask. But there are other best-practices for preventing exposure to the dust (the dust contains crystalline silica).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd just reach for my P100 respirator, but I bought it long before covid made high-quality respirators scarce and subject to counterfeiting. The P100 filter is perhaps overkill for this job, but suits some other needs and doesn't (or didn't) cost a lot more than an N100 or N95/P95/N99/P99 filter. The P indicates oil resistance (which is not needed for your specific job, but doesn't hurt to have) while 100 .vs. 95 is a "more is better" filtering efficacy rating. It's my "go to" serious "dust mask" (and unsuited for covid purposes since it has an exhaust valve that sends my unfiltered exhalations directly out into the world.) You have to get one that properly fits your face for it to be effective.

In the present era, you will have to be (more) careful about possible fake products, as covid has turned a small market for counterfeit respiratory protection into a large market for [counterfeit respiratory protection](https://www.cdc.gov/niosh/npptl/usernotices/counterfeitResp.html), which may appear to be correctly rated, but which will probably not perform as advertised, since it's just got to look similar to the product it's ripping off.